# What is the Difference Between Awaiter (GetAwaiter) and ContinueWith

Tags: .net, multithreading, .net-4.0

In .net 4.0, I use Task.ContinueWith regularly.  But then [I spotted "task.GetAwaiter()"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14171923/284758) which seems to have the same purpose.

What is the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're targeting .NET 4, you'd use `ContinueWith`.

In general, you wouldn't normally use `task.GetAwaiter()`.  This method exists in order to support the `await` keyword, and is not part of .NET 4 (it's added in 4.5).  This isn't something you'd typically use directly yourself, but instead write it as part of an `async` method.