# Async/Await with Entity Framework 6.1.1 and impersonation

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, async-await

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS that is retrieving data from multiple sources (all SQL Server). With each data source, I have to impersonate a different Active Directory user to connect to the database. I am using Entity Framework v6.1.1 for two of the data sources. Integrated Security is set to True in the connection strings, too.

I use the example below to set the impersonated user, where the impersonated user is a `System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext` that I set from configuration:

```
internal async Task<List<string>> GetItemsByLookupItemsAsync(List<string> lookupItems) 
{
    var result = new List<string>();

    using (var db = new EntityFrameworkDb()) 
    {

        var query = from item in db.Table
                    where lookupItems.Contains(item.LookupColumn)
                    select item.StringColumn;

        var queryResult = new List<string>();
        using (GetImpersonatedUser())
        {
            queryResult.AddRange(await query.ToListAsync());
        }

        result.AddRange(queryResult.OrderBy(e => e));
    }

    return result;
}
```

The problem is that the previous code throws a `SqlException` saying that the account running the web service can not log on to the database. It appears that when I hit the `await` I lose the impersonation context.

What are some suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: My usual recommendation is to not use async for database calls because it almost never does anything good.

Comment: @usr Can you elaborate on that a bit more?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I have: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25087273/122718
 If you doubt this statement, try to clearly express why calling the database using async IO is helpful. It is hard to come up with reasons.

Comment: @usr How about the latest comment by stephan? About the type of database being able to scale better than before. If it isn't too expensive, why not take advantage?

Comment: Please read this: http://blog.codeishard.net/2012/09/17/await-async-mvc-and-impersonation/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the [`legacyImpersonationPolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229296(v=vs.110).aspx) to `false` and [`alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229553(v=vs.110).aspx) to `true` inside your `web.config` and restart IIS

```
<configuration>
   <runtime>
     <legacyImpersonationPolicy enabled="false"/>
    <alwaysFlowImpersonationPolicy enabled="true"/>   
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This worked, both in IIS in web.config and in my client app.config. Thanks for your help.

Comment: It seems that legacyImpersonationPolicy enabled="true" is the default. This seems strange to me.. Do you know why it is like that?