# Do synchronous sockets still allow for external user action?

Tags: c#, sockets, asynchronous, chat

I'm developing a client-server infrastructure with file sharing, chat, and some server tracking functions.

I need to create three persistent TCP connections for each since they'll use separate protocols and, often, separate server instances. I haven't begun to design the communication stuff because I'm uncertain as to which type of system I should design it as: async or sync?

If I choose Async, what benefits will it give to me relative to the three other protocols?

If I choose Sync, will two chat messages sent in a short time span from each other, for example, be subject to one of them being lost, or delayed, due to the other one's send process?

I hope my question isn't too unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between what you can accomplish with sync and with async. The features of the sockets API do not change. Only the call mechanism changes.

[The benefits of sync and async are non-functional in nature.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25087273/122718) See also: [Should we switch to use async I/O by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12793749/should-we-switch-to-use-async-i-o-by-default/12796711#12796711)

This answers your question as asked. If there is some specific issue or confusion leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks. All the talk about Async and multitasking made me think that it was the only way for a program to multitask. I was worried this would limit my user.