# Will the second Await call of two wait for the first to finish?

Tags: c#, async-await

If I have two Tasks that I am Awaiting:

```
await FirstTask();
await SecondTask();
```

Will the SecondTask only begin execution once FirstTask is complete?

Thanks

Comment: Yes that is correct

Comment: Well, what did you find out while debugging your code?

Comment: @RandRandom That's actually a pretty old, mostly unknown technique invented by Daniel Ebugging in the late 80's. Using that technique you can look through your code _step by step_ and see what's going on, that's crazy!

Comment: Related: [Async/Await - is it *concurrent*?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7663101/async-await-is-it-concurrent) and [When I “await” an “async” method does it become synchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32482275/when-i-await-an-async-method-does-it-become-synchronous)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes that is what happens.

```
await FirstTask();
await SecondTask(); // doesn't start until FirstTask() finishes
```

If you want to have them run in parallel, and await both, you can use [`Task.WhenAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.whenall?view=net-5.0)

```
var task1 = FirstTask();
var task2 = SecondTask(); // starts right away, even if FirstTask is still busy
await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
```