# How to fix my WebAPI2 controllers to use async Task for scability

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, async-await

We have recently developed an ASP.Net WebAPI2 that is using the synchronous calls across various layers as below.

[image]

Now I have learnt that it's best to use the `Async Task` approach for stability reasons but as the code is already developed for most of the functionality using sync calls, I was wondering what is the best way to convert the calls I have.

Say this is how my code is initially written:

```
[Route("user/{userId}/feeds ")]
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<NewsFeedItem> GetNewsFeedItemsForUserAsync(string userId)
{
    return newsFeedService.GetNewsFeedItemsForUser(userId);
}
```

I can convert this to something like this:

```
[Route("user/{userId}/feeds ")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<NewsFeedItem>> GetNewsFeedItemsForUserAsync(string userId)
{
    return await Task.Run(()=>newsFeedService.GetNewsFeedItemsForUser(userId));
}
```

But, if I understand correctly, I don't think that will help me scale up my website as it will still end up using the thread pool thread.

The only other option I see to modify all the layers and all the functions to use `async` but that seems like a lot of work.

So I was wondering if anyone here had to undergo a similar exercise and what is the best way to address the problem.

Regards
Kiran

Comment: `async` all the way...

Comment: The best way would be that `newsFeedService` offers an `async` method, so you can just `await` it from the controller. Meanwhile, `newsFeedService` should have an `async` DAO / Repository, which should have `async` persistence strategies, which should have `async` methods, which should communicate asynchronously to the underlying database... (The point is that you will have to convert all the execution flow to `async`)

Comment: Also if `await` is the last statement of the method, you can remove it. After removing it, if you're left with no `await` statements, you can drop the `async` keyword too.

Comment: I will link to my standard posts about whether to use async or not: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25087273/122718 Why does the EF 6 tutorial use asychronous calls?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12796711/122718 Should we switch to use async I/O by default?
You probably will discover that you should not use async because under ASP.NET most usages of async result in no benefit whatsoever.

Comment: @usr: Those were nice discussions, I learnt a lot from those comments. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> only other option I see to modify all the layers and all the functions
>   to use async but that seams like a lot of work.

You're right, writing up a whole new data access layer that exposes true asynchronous methods is hard work, as it usually needs to be re-written from the ground up. But, if you know you *actually need* scalability and you've identified it as your current bottleneck, then it will end up being worth it.

Wrapping your code in `Task.Run` will benefit nothing, as you stated yourself, because what async does exactly is free a thread-pool thread while it does IO, where here you're actually consuming *another* thread, other than the one that ASP.NET runtime already provided you with.

To conclude, there is no easy magic fix to make this all work, it will require you to re-write/add async endpoints to the calling code.

Comment: Both ADO.NET and Entity Framework provide asynchronous methods. Changing the data layer may not be so difficult

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov: Thanks, looks like only way is to do the hard way. how I wish if there was a some way to flag the compiler (say using attributes) to make any I/O call as await in the full call chain :)