# Avoid returning type Task<Object> from an async function when using HttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, async-await, httpclient

I am making HTTP calls using the `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`. It seems that all calls must be asynchronous.

Let's say I have a project structure of the following:
MVC Web App -> Business Layer -> Data Layer

In the Data Layer I am making HTTP calls to a Web API to return data and I end up using a function like this:

```
public async Task<IList<Product>> GetProducts()
{
     HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products");
     string data = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
     IList<Product> products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Product>>(data);

     return products;
}
```

this then goes through to the BusinessLayer:

```
public Task<IList<Product>> GetProducts(string name = null)
{
     return _repository.GetProducts(name);
}
```

Then finally in the MVC controller:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    Task<IList<Product>> ProductsTask = _manager.GetProducts();

    IList<Product> ProductsNonTask = products.Result.ToList();

    return View();
}
```

Do I really have to make every single function return a list of type `Task<IList<Product>>` leading up to my MVC controller? As you can see in the MVC controller I have to retrieve the products initially with Task wrapped around them. The debugger looks kind of strange when I go to view the list of products through it. So then as you can see I convert them to a regular list of product.

I am wondering if it is the correct thing to do to have all of my functions return type `Task<IList<Product>>` all the way up to my MVC controller or if there is a workaround so that my functions can still return the a standard list of product but continue to use the async capabilities of the `HttpClient`?

**UPDATE: Is there anything wrong with doing the following:**

```
public IList<Product> GetProducts()
{
     Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = client.GetAsync("api/products");
     if (response.Result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
     {
          string data = response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
          IList<Product> products = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IList<Product>>(data);

          retVal = products;
     }
}
```

Comment: `Is there anything wrong with doing the following:` Yes, the code doesn't compile (for a number of different reasons).  You could have figured that out by simply trying to compile it.

Comment: I apologize I accidentally left the await keyword in since I copied and pasted and changed. It is fixed now.

Comment: The code still won't compile, again, for a number of different reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the operation to actually be asynchronous it needs to be asynchronous all the way up.

The minute you block on a `Task` with `Wait` or `Result` it's no longer asynchronous.

So, no. Either use async all the way up or be don't use it at all.

> I wonder... if there is a workaround so that my functions can still return the a standard list of product but continue to use the async capabilities of the HttpClient?

No, there isn't really.

You should probably just make your code asynchronous as it comes with many benefits in scalability and performance. But if you're against doing so you can use `WebClient` that has synchronous web operations.

Comment: If that is the case I am trying to find a way to still use the async method of the HttpClient without returning type Task for my function. For example I think I can do something like: Task<HttpResponseMessage> response = client.GetAsync("api/customers"); Then my function itself wouldn't have to return type Task because I am doing away with the await keyword.

Comment: @BlakeRivell Don't. Either use async all the way up or just avoid it altogether. Don't try and mix as this will only get you into troubles.

Comment: @BlakeRivell more here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/13/10293638.aspx

Comment: Can you read my first comment I believe this would be the work around... is avoiding using the await keyword in my repository.

Comment: @BlakeRivell You don't have to use `await`. But you do need to return a `Task`.

Comment: Alright, so you are saying since HttpClient forces asynchronous I should use it all the way up. Can you please check the update in my post at the bottom and let me know if that is a bad idea... I guess this is considered blocking, but what if I don't care about it being asynchronous?

Comment: @BlakeRivell If you don't want your program to be asynchronous then that's fine.  **Don't use asynchronous operations** and use synchronous operations instead.

Comment: @BlakeRivell your update won't compile. You can't use `await` in a non-`async` method.

Comment: @Servy I am not sure if you have worked with the HttpClient yet but it forces asynchronous operations since it is making web calls so I don't have a choice.

Comment: @BlakeRivell Then don't use `HttpClient`.  It was created specifically to provide asynchronous counterparts to the previously existing synchronous APIs.  If you don't want to use an asynchronous API, then don't use the API specifically created to be asynchronous.

Comment: What else can I use... I have a feeling I should be using it since I am creating a Web API... To give to others to call..

Comment: @BlakeRivell [`WebClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) and its [`DownloadString(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Answer (score 1):

> Do I really have to make every single function return a list of type Task> leading up to my MVC controller?

Yes, you have to and you didn't even catch all places because `Index` itself must be async, too.

Async is really infectious. Use when necessary, not by default.

Comment: Do I have to use it int his case just because I am using HttpClient?

Comment: HttpClient forces async IO (unfortunately) but you can block on it if that's good enough for you. That saves you from the "infection". See this to decide: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25087273/122718 Why does the EF 6 tutorial use asychronous calls?
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12796711/122718 Should we switch to use async I/O by default?

Comment: Blocking on the tasks returned by HttpClient never deadlocks, btw. This is safe because HttpClient does not use the synchronization context that might be installed.

Comment: Can you see my update that I made to my post and tell me if this is an acceptable form of blocking?

Comment: The code is not quite finished, need to remove the await and block there as well. But basically this is fine. Please see what I linked to to understand the performance implications. How many such calls will be made per second and how long will each take?

Comment: Yeah I apologize I accidentally left it in there. Thanks for the links and info!

Comment: You could use WebClient as well for this. It has a synchronous API. Servy correctly suggests doing that and I'd endorse that as well. On the other hand it does not have Json deserialization built in. So unfortunate that HttpClient forces async access.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101822/discussion-between-blake-rivell-and-usr).